# What does {built-in method select} do in Python 3?

Tags: python, profiling, built-in, cprofile

When profiling my application using `cProfile` and `pstats`, one of the rows reads:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     6    2.940    0.490    2.940    0.490 {built-in method select}
```

What does this method do and when is it executed?

Comment: [`select.select`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.select)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[select.select](http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.select) is an interface to the Unix [select()](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?select%202) system call.